# How to add 2 strings to an array and display one down the other

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have two strings i need to add those to the array and display one down the other

```
const str1 = "SamsungGalaxy A52"
const str2 = "SamsungGalaxy A53"

let arr=[]

arr.push(str1,str2)
```

and I want to display like

```
  SamsungGalaxy A52
  SamsungGalaxy A53
```

Comment: Why is there an array? What has this to do with the expected result? Where should the output happen (console, DOM, ...)? What have you tried so far to solve this on your own?

Comment: your goal is unclear. You simply want to display every value in a single line? where? in an Html page?

Comment: You have mistake in your code, in the first argument of `push` method you wrote `strl` but it must be `str1`

Comment: @EzioMercer i have corrected Thanks

Comment: @R9102 What do you want? To show the list in conosle or in HTML page?

Comment: in the HTML page, i need to display these items

Comment: @R9102 It will be a static array or it will be dynamic array?

Comment: it will be a static array , what ever I have shown here I want to display it one down the other
I think I can use for each loop and display this

Comment: exactly, like @EzioMercer answer. With a foreach you walk trought the array and then you can add to te page as you want. Like a list of <li>, like simple text in a <div> inserting a <br> after each element and so on, hundreds possibility

Comment: @Andrea_86 apart from the question what if the products is a string say const pro = {products:''} is that necessary to create the array and push it to pro.products = ???? and display it?? what would be the good approach?

Comment: i did not understand what you mean. If is necessary to put in an array or to print to DOM (or where ever you want) only you know. I understood that are static string, so for print them all you have to put them into an array and then iterate it. Best way could be to create directly an array of strings and then do what you need. If you put them into an object is the same, you always need to iterate over a collection of object (array are always good) but the meaning dosn't change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like it:

```js
const product_1 = "SamsungGalaxy A52";
const product_2 = "SamsungGalaxy A53";

let products = [];

products.push(product_1, product_2);

const ul = document.querySelector('ul');

for (const product of products) {
  const li = document.createElement('li');
  li.textContent = product;
  ul.append(li);
}
```

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
</ul>
```

Comment: @R9102 You can also use `forEach` method, I'm just used to using `for of` loop

Comment: apart from the question  what if the products is a string

say const pro = {products:''}

is that necessary to create the array and push it to pro.products = ???? and display it??

what would be the good approach?

Comment: @R9102 I didn't clearly understand you. You have string like `"A, B, C"` and you want to show them individually?

Comment: const pro = {products:''}
const abc = ["SamsungGalaxy A52","SamsungGalaxy A53"]
pro.product should be 
SamsungGalaxy A52
SamsungGalaxy A53


not in html

Comment: @R9102 `pro.products = abs.join(' ')`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to push two values to an array, you can do it with `arr.push(str1, str2);` or `arr.push(str1); arr.push(str2);`

You could create a `ul` & `li` list to display this list in UI.

```js
const str1 = "SamsungGalaxy A52"
const str2 = "SamsungGalaxy A53"

let arr=[]

arr.push(str1);
arr.push(str2);
// arr.push(str1, str2);

console.log(arr);

const ul = document.createElement('ul');

for (const item of arr) {
  const li = document.createElement('li');
  li.textContent = item;
  ul.append(li);
}

document.querySelector('body').appendChild(ul)
```

Comment: [`.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) can handle multiple arguments. The output is not what OP has shown in the question (and is only on multiple lines in the snippets console)

Comment: As conclusion: 

The arr.push "pushes" the value in order of calling the method

Comment: I dont know why this answer has got two downvotes? If displaying the list to UI was the issue, I have included that. It was not clear whether the user wish to display the list in console or in UI. Have added that part aswell.

Comment: @Nitheesh Your answer looks good for me I have upvoted thanks

Comment: @Nitheesh apart from the question what if the products is a string say const pro = {products:''} is that necessary to create the array and push it to pro.products = ???? and display it?? what would be the good approach?

Comment: @R9102 not clear. What is the structure of the input?

Comment: const pro = {products:''}
const abc = ["SamsungGalaxy A52","SamsungGalaxy A53"]
pro.product should be 
SamsungGalaxy A52
SamsungGalaxy A53


not in html

Comment: @R9102 Like this `const str1 = { products: "SamsungGalaxy A52" }
const str2 = { products: "SamsungGalaxy A53" }`?

Answer (score 1):

you can build string and add as `innerHTML`

```js
const product_1 = "SamsungGalaxy A52";
const product_2 = "SamsungGalaxy A53";

const products = [];
products.push(product_1, product_2);

// or just
// const products = [product_1, product_2];

document.querySelector("#app").innerHTML = products
  .map((product) => `<div>${product}</div>`)
  .join("");
```

```css
#app {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
```